# Comparing Data Read from NFC Tag

Tags: android, nfc

Hi I am reading data from a NFC Tag and  trying to compare it with a String but the if loop is getting failed while comparison of string.My code for reading NFC data and comparing it with String is as. Thank You.

```
   Parcelable[] messages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
                //NdefMessage message = ndef.getNdefMessage();
                if (messages != null) {
                    NdefMessage[] ndefMessages = new NdefMessage[messages.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                        ndefMessages[i] = (NdefMessage) messages[i];
                    }
                NdefRecord record = ndefMessages[0].getRecords()[0];

                byte[] payload = record.getPayload();
                String text = new String(payload);
                txtRead.setText(text);


                                if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("silent")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  
                    audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT); 
                }
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An NDEF text record contains, before the actual text, information about the text's language and, more important, the text encoding (character set used). You should inspect those bytes to know whether the actual text is encoded in UTF-8 or UTF-16 (and use that for converting the bytes to a String).

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I removed the text language and text encoding from payload. Now I am getting the String what I want...

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is only with if condition try this code

```
if(text.toLowerCase().contains("silent")){
...
...
}
```