# Android NFC Tag String Comparison

Tags: string, tags, comparison, nfc

I am having a problem with comparing two strings, one coming from a NFC tag, and another from an xml file.
The code I use to write the tag looks like this:

```
   private NdefMessage getTagAsNdef(Card new_card) 
    {
        boolean addAAR = false;
        String unique_id = new_card.getCardId();       
        byte[] bytes = unique_id.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        byte[] payload = new byte[bytes.length + 1]; 
        NdefRecord rtdUriRecord = new NdefRecord(
        NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload);
        if(addAAR) 
        {
            NdefRecord new_record = null;
            try 
            {
                new_record = createRecord(new_card);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {rtdUriRecord, new_record}); 
        } else 
        {
            return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] 
        {
                rtdUriRecord});
        }
    }
```

I tried to remove all the language and encoding info usually set in the payload following the advice found here:
[Comparing Data Read from NFC Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470530/comparing-data-read-from-nfc-tag)
The comparison I do here after reading the tag however always fails, although the string values printed in the log are identical:

```
looking at this_card_id -6465415649291849135
      compare to tag_id -6465415649291849135
```

I got the length of strings to show the problem:

```
looking at this_card_id 20
      compare to tag_id 21
```

So the tag id has a hidden character which I have been unable to get rid of.
Here is the code for the comparison:

```
private void associateWithCardsFile(String tag_id)
{
    String method = "associateWithCardsFile";
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, method+" tag_id "+tag_id);
    tag_id.trim();
    boolean found = false;
    Enumeration e = cards.keys();
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, method+" cards "+cards.size());
    while (e.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String this_card_id = (String)e.nextElement();
        this_card_id.trim();
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, method+" looking at this_card_id "+this_card_id.length());
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, method+"       compare to tag_id "+tag_id.length());
        String card_id_str = UtilityTo.encodeThisString(this_card_id, "UTF-8");
        String tag_id_str = UtilityTo.encodeThisString(tag_id, "UTF-8");
        if (card_id_str.equals(tag_id_str))
        {
            Card matching_card = cards.get(this_card_id);
            String word = UtilityTo.getWord(matching_card);
            Toast.makeText(this, word, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, method+" 1 match"+matching_card.getText()+" "+matching_card.getDefinition()+" "+matching_card.getWordType());
            turn_cards.add(matching_card);
            found = true;
            showCards();
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not a game card!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, method+" card not found");
    }
}
```

In the UtilityTo class, I have this method which works well for working with foreign languages.

```
public static String encodeThisString(String original_value, String encoding)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] utf8Bytes = original_value.getBytes(encoding);
        String new_value = new String(utf8Bytes, encoding);
        return new_value;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException n)
    {
        n.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I also tried some advice from StackOverflow like this: tag_id_str = new String(tag_id.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ascii") to no avail.
Can someone please explain how to either write the tag so that there are no hidden characters and basic string comparisons will work, or how to modify the string from the tag so it will equate to a string with the same number.
Thanks.

p.s.
Here is the write method from the Android Developer NFC Basics that I started using after writing this.  It causes the same problem as noted above: the tag_id is 1 character longer than card_id from the xml file.

```
public NdefRecord createRecord(String payload) 
{
    String language = "en";
    boolean encodeInUtf8 = true;
    byte[] langBytes = language.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    Charset utfEncoding = encodeInUtf8 ? Charset.forName("UTF-8") : Charset.forName("UTF-16");
    byte[] textBytes = payload.getBytes(utfEncoding);
    int utfBit = encodeInUtf8 ? 0 : (1 << 7);
    char status = (char) (utfBit + langBytes.length);
    byte[] data = new byte[1 + langBytes.length + textBytes.length];
    data[0] = (byte) status;
    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, data, 1, langBytes.length);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, data, 1 + langBytes.length, textBytes.length);
    NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,
    NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], data);
    return record;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [TextRecord](https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/source/browse/ndeftools/src/org/ndeftools/wellknown/TextRecord.java) and see whether that resolves your issues. Probably your encode/decode Text record is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the help Thomas.  Since my needs are pretty simple with NFC, and I was almost finished with the read and write methods, I was able to fix the problem eventually.  
NDF Tools looks like a good option.  If I was starting at the beginning again, I probably would have saved some time by using it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I only store a long on each tag, I made a method to exclude all other characters from the tag message.
Now I can compare the tag id string to an id string from an xml file.

```
private String removeHiddenCharacters(String message)
{
  String dash = "-";
  char d = dash.charAt(0);
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
  {
    char c = message.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c))
    {
        sb.append(c);
    } else if (c == d)
    {
        sb.append(d);
    }
  }
  String result = new String(sb);
  Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, " result "+result);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you consider the external type record? Its payload is a (any) byte array so there would be less sources of problems.